# What is the clock measure by clock() and clock64() in CUDA?

Tags: cuda, nvidia, clock

What is the clock measure by `clock()` and `clock64()` in CUDA ?

According to [CUDA documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#time-function) the clock is  'per-multiprocessor counter'.  According to my understanding this refers to Primary GPU clock (not the shader clock).

But when I measure clock counts and convert it to time values using primary GPU clock frequency, the results I get are twice large as the real values (I measure real values using the kernel execution time from  host code using cuda events). This suggests `clock()` returns the shader clock frequency instead of the primary GPU clock.

How can I solve this confusion ?

EDIT : 
I calculated the primary GPU clock frequency by dividing the clock rate I get from cudaGetDeviceProperties by 2. As far as I understand the value given by [cudaGetDeviceProperties](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__DEVICE_g5aa4f47938af8276f08074d09b7d520c.html) is the shader clock frequency.

Comment: **primary GPU clock / Graphics Core Clock / Graphic Clock / Core Clock** : Clock rate the the Streaming Multiprocessor runs. <br/> 

**shader clock/ Shader Core Clock / Processor Clock / GPU clock** : Clock rate that execution units (CUDA cores) run. This is twice the value of primary GPU clock. 
This is how I have understood it.

Comment: I can confirm that on Fermi devices, `cudaDeviceProp::clockRate` is the shader clock rate, that is, double value compared to the "primary" GPU clock. On Kepler devices, the two are the same. The answer would be more certain if you tell which device you are using. Not sure about `clock()` and `clock64()` - you are probably right in your assumption.

Comment: I think @Optimus is referring to the following: On older GPUs (e.g. Fermi family), the execution units run at twice the clock rate of the rest of the graphics domain (this is sometimes refefred to as the "hot clock"). `nvidia-smi` reports these as "graphics" and "SM" clocks, respectively  For example on my Fermi-based Quadro 2000, the former is reported as 625 MHz, the latter as 1251 MHz. Best I know, starting with Kepler all of the non-memory domain of a GPU runs at the same speed, i.e. there is no more SM hot clock.

Comment: My device is **Quadro 2000D**. The clock frequency given from 'cudaDeviceProp::clockRate' is 1251 MHz which is the shader clock frequency. The reason for my confusion is in the [CUDA documentation](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__DEVICE_g5aa4f47938af8276f08074d09b7d520c.html) they say 'per-multiprocessor counter' which refer to the primary GPU clock.

Comment: @njuffa : How did you get 625 MHz ? Is it from a datasheet or from a CUDA function ?

Comment: This language may be used intentionally. The counter underlying `clock()` could be tied to different internal clocks on different GPUs and it may not be directly convertible to units of time in the presence of dynamic clock boosting and power capping. You could file a request through the NVIDIA bug reporting system to have the documentation clarified.

Comment: @Optimus: I ran `nvidia-smi -q` and looked under the `Max Clocks` section.

Comment: @ParkYoung-Bae : exactly. So the issue is the `clock()` uses **streaming multiprocessor** frequency while `cudaDeviceProp::clockRate` returns the **streaming processor** frequency.

Comment: Does somebody want to provide an answer?  Fermi device `clock()` is driven from the hotclock.  OP effectively answered the question in the question.

Comment: Ok, I'll summarize it to an answer...

Answer (score 5):

It's true that [CUDA documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#time-function) says `clock()` and `clock64()` returns 'per-multiprocessor counter'. But in Fermi architecture what `clock()` and `clock64()` actually returns is the shader clock counter.

The `clockRate` returned by [cudaGetDeviceProperties](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__DEVICE_g5aa4f47938af8276f08074d09b7d520c.html) is the shader clock frequency.

So to compute the time, we have to divide the clock count from `clock()` or `clock64()` by shader clock frequency you get from [cudaGetDeviceProperties](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__DEVICE_g5aa4f47938af8276f08074d09b7d520c.html).

Comment: I would caution against converting `clock()` or `clock64()` counts to units of time based on the value of `cudaDeviceProp::clockRate`, since the underlying clock can change dynamically, due to clock boosting and clock throttling. If I recall correctly, clock throttling to cap power consumption has been around since Fermi, and dynamic clock boost was introduced with Kepler.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. But in my case the values I got were accurate. I compared the results I got from `clock()` with the time measurements I got from CUDA events and they were almost similar.